# SELECT ... LIMIT 0,1 syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-limit

```
    for($nr = 0; $nr < 2; $nr++){

        print $nr; print(gettype($nr));   // prints 0integer 

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM phcdl_files 
        ORDER BY file_id DESC LIMIT '$nr',1") 
        or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
```

Trying to run the query above but I'm having troubles because of syntax.
Running it on PhpMyAdmin with Limit 0,1 works good however

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Does it give you errors?

Comment: You've incorrectly placed quotes around the `$nr` value. Instead use prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: @Dai: there are issues with bound parameters used with `LIMIT` clause. As soon as it's an integer - it's trivial to sanitize it and put into query directly.

Comment: always use prepared statements, to shield you from sql injection.

Comment: @timh although using prepared statements are great, i cannot see any cause for alarm in this query.. there's no user generated data, just a system generated integer.. so he's safe from sql injection

Comment: give me a minute to try it. SQL injection isn't a problem because I'm only using it myself to import an old website to WordPress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with -

```
"SELECT * FROM phcdl_files ORDER BY file_id DESC LIMIT $nr,1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you're adding quote around the 0.

Your SQL query should look like:

```
"SELECT * FROM phcdl_files ORDER BY file_id DESC LIMIT $nr, 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

> remove single quotation of $nr veriable from query

```
QUERY = "select * from tb_name order by id desc limit $nr , 1"
```